# how to pass parameter from jsp to servlet when variables are declared in another java file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page and a servlet for it. I'm trying to pass a parameter from the servlet to the jsp page and that works fine. Please note that this parameter or attribute is declared in another java class as static final.
But when I'm trying to pass this parameter again to servlet I see the value null.**strong text**

Variables.java

```
public static final String VAR_date="date";
```

JSP

```
String date=request.getAttribute(VAR_date);       //this values is fetched
<A href='Servlet?VAR_date=<%=date%>'</A>     //problem occurs here when                      sending date back to Servlet
```

Servlet

```
doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletresponse res)

String date=req.getParameter(VAR_date); // value is null
```

I dont know if the Syntax is different when you pass a variable which has been declared in java file, or if this is wrong.
 Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you access it directly, since it is a static variable?(ClassName.VAR_date)

Comment: I think he wants to use constants to prevent typos, the date will be the name of the param on client and server side.

Comment: If I have understood you question it should be `<A href='Servlet?date=<%=date%>'>label</A>` or even better `<A href='Servlet?date=${date}'>label</A>`. Currently your parameter name is `"VAR_date"` and you try to read `"date"`

Comment: Thank you @SergeBallesta! That worked like a charm!:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to either pass it to a field, and submit it (it can be hidden as well), which's **name** should be the VAR_date. Then you can read it in the servlet. *Or alternatively, you can set it into session, and read it in the servlet (then possibly remove it), but I'd not recommend that.*

The input thing looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<%= Variables.VAR_date =>" value="anything you want to submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Servlet, add statement for importing `Variables` class and then directly access the required variable as follows:-

```
Variables.VAR_date
```

still if you want to pass from JSP then set date value in some hidden variables and then get hidden variables' values from those hidden parameters.